# How Skanda in North India to Kandha (Lord muruga) in South India?

Tags: gods, worship, kartikeya

While reading an article I got this line,

> The references to Murugan can be traced back to the first millennium
>   BCE.    There are references to Murugan in Kautilya's Arthashastra, in
>   the works of Patanjali, in Kalidasa's epic poem the Kumarasambhavam.
>
> The Kushanas, who governed from what is today Peshawar, and the
>   Yaudheyas, a republican clan in the Punjab, struck coins bearing the
>   image of Skanda

Could any one please explain or suggest some reading to know how Lord muruga has evolved as Tamil god in Tamilnadu?

If due to muslim invasion Kanda worship was abolished in North India, how worship of Ganesha and Siva still exists and why none of other gods has any relation to language Tamil?

EDIT:
I dont think its a duplicate. My question is how Lord muruga evloved as tamil god.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Kartikeya not worshiped much compared to lord Shiva, lord Ganesha and goddess Parvati?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/948/why-is-kartikeya-not-worshiped-much-compared-to-lord-shiva-lord-ganesha-and-god).

Comment: `...why none of other gods has any relation to language Tamil?` Do you know that Lord Shiva was the leader of the first Tamil Sangam?

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran That is a very interesting one..(i hope gubera and murugan was also there in first sangam)If Lord siva was the leader of first tamil sangam why we dont have any place as like kedarnath here?? or it was there and submerged in sea? When you put Lord siva to a layman as me the first thought will be himalayas. Am not trying to make north and south india clash but Just trying to sort out my doubt.

Comment: We have a Jyothirlingam at Rameswaram. The entire Annamalai hill is considered as a manifestation of Lord Shiva. Shiva is sometimes referred to as **தென்னாடுடைய சிவன்** which means that Shiva is the lord of South India. There are also many Swayambhu Lingams in Tamilnadu. So, don't restrict Shiva to North India alone. Don't forget that Shaivism was the major religion of South India during the Chola rule. I doubt that Gubera was there in Tamil Sangam. But Lord Muruga was the leader of the Second Sangam. It was Sage Agashtya who formulated the grammar of Tamil language.

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran Could you please tell me some books to read in detail about it.. I found an interesting answer at [link](http://aanmikam.blogspot.com/2013/05/blog-post_6598.html
) ..

Answer (score 3):

Hinduism as we know today is not what it was 2000, 3000 years ago. And still today, there are several gods who were added later to the pantheon and roots are not known (or made conviently). Speaking of Murukan, Velavan, Kandan (not Kanda) epochs great pride for a Tamil. It is even hard to write about him in English. However, for the sake of explaining this and for the benefit of non-Tamil, here we go. Velavan or Velan, is a simple god with close ties to nature, or nature worship. There is a obvious push to make [Kartikeya and Murugan](http://murugan.org/research/skanda-chowdhury.htm) to be one and same, they both differ vastly in the setup.

[Murukan](http://www.tamilvu.org/slet/servlet/srchlxpg?editor=%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%A9%E0%AF%8D) is one of the five gods responsible for five ways of [Tamil living spaces](http://www.tamilvu.org/slet/l0100/l0100uri.jsp?song_no=951&book_id=1&head_id=3). He is seen in [Indus valley scripts](http://murugan.org/research/mahadevan.htm) (well before the vedic deities?). Worship of spear ([Vel](http://madhavipanthal.blogspot.com/2012/02/blog-post.html)) and celebration of spring. Murugan is more often worshiped as war god and always young (the word Murugan meaning the young one).

Comment: Indus valley is not before the Vedic deities. The references available are outdated and astronomical references to 7000 BCE in RgVeda is one of the several evidence of a much earlier date of Vedic Civilization.

Comment: Agreed. No one knows for sure, and my actual answer was specific to this line of questioning. I am sure in another setting, another question, I would have a cited different sources and different answer altogether. As I said, this is debatable.