# What is Ayyappa and Hanuman god of?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, hanuman, ayyappa

Shiva is the god of Destruction,Vishnu is the god of preservation and Brahma is the god of creation.Durga is the goddess of power,Lakshmi is the goddess of wealth and Sarawati is the goddess of wisdom.In addition to that,Ganesha is the god of success and Skanda is the god of war.What about Ayypappa and Hanuman?

Comment: Ayyappa is known for his skills in warfare tactics, judicial laws and in the Vedas.
He is also known to provide refuge for all who come to him.<br>
Hence devotees chant <i>"Swamiye Sharanam Ayyappa"</i>.<br>He is known as the only son of both Shiva and Hari (Vishnu) Hanuman is known for his Speed,Strength and Loyalty.<br>
Hanuman is also a <i>chiranjeevi</i> {Immortal}

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Hanuman and Ayyappa are technically not gods, so they're not gods "of" something.  Hanuman was a Vanara who is the son of Vayu the wind god and Anjana, although he's often considered an incarnation of Shiva.  Ayyappa is another name for prince Manikandan of Pandalam, who was a human incarnation of the god Dharma Shasta as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10134/36 In any case, you can still receive blessings by worshipping them, just like you can receive blessings by worshipping Rama and Krishna even though they were human incarnations of Vushnu.

Comment: Hanuman can be considered as God of Success and Devotion.

Comment: @Anil Kumar thank you!What about ayyappa?I have heard that he is the god of growth but I don't understand what that means.please explain.