# Why Lord Muruga is not worshiped in north india as much as he is in south india?

Tags: worship, ganesha, kartikeya

Why  North Indians don't worship [Lord Murugan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartikeya)(Karthikeya) as much as they worship Lord Ganesha?

But this doesn't happen in South India.

Comment: Actually Ganesha reserves the status of "first to be worshiped"..So he is to be always invoked first wherever it mite be..As regards Karthikeya he is the over ruling deity of Mars(Kuja/Mangal)..and the direction that Mars denote is south..This mite just indicate why Karthikeya is more popular in the South..

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/948/why-is-kartikeya-not-worshiped-much-compared-to-lord-shiva-lord-ganesha-and-god

Comment: It's because after Kartikeya lost his competition with Ganesha, he went to South India, where he revealed the Tamil language to Agastya.  So he's called the "Tamil Kadavul" which means Tamil god or god of Tamil.