# Is kartikeya married or unmarried? Why is he not worshipped widely even after he had always protected mankind from evil powers?

Tags: gods, worship, kartikeya

Why is he not worshipped widely even after he had always protected mankind from evil powers? Can anyone answer it? I know he is worshipped widely in south India and north Indians think he is responsible for creating widows as he is a war god. But that's not fair because all he ever did was to save mankind from evil powers. So are we not supposed to be thankful to him?

Comment: Yes married and his two wives are- Devasena and Valli.

Comment: He is worshipped widely. He is married. Very much related question  [Why is Kartikeya not worshiped much compared to lord Shiva, lord Ganesha and goddess Parvati?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/948/why-is-kartikeya-not-worshiped-much-compared-to-lord-shiva-lord-ganesha-and-god). The question about worship is already answered.

Comment: Do the North Indians really think so?

Comment: Possible this question is already answered - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4100/wives-of-lord-kartikeya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wives of Lord Kartikeya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4100/wives-of-lord-kartikeya) and [Why is Kartikeya not worshiped much compared to lord Shiva, lord Ganesha and goddess Parvati?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/948/why-is-kartikeya-not-worshiped-much-compared-to-lord-shiva-lord-ganesha-and-god)

Comment: But in North India he is a bachelor who has vowed not to marry